# Is it possible to play the game without joining the Minutemen?

Tags: fallout-4

Is it possible to play the game without joining the Minutemen?

What happens if you don't join any factions? Are there still quests to do?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to play the game without joining the Minutemen, for example if you were to start a new game and immediately head out of the vault to the Old Church (Railroad headquarters) you get some new dialogue (since you're unable to tell them that somebody sent you) and an offer to join the Railroad. I would assume this to be the same if you were to head to the Cambridge Police station and join the Brotherhood of Steel also.

It is not possible as far as I'm aware to complete the game without joining any faction, as faction assistance is required for some of the quests and while I've tried contacting the Institute before communicating with anybody else I haven't found a way to achieve this.

There are of course plenty of side missions and areas to explore, so you could "play" the game without joining a faction and still get many hours of enjoyment out of it but in order to progress the main story line you need to come into contact with at least one of the factions.